# SQL fetch values from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi having a problem on how to structure my sql statment would appreciate any help on how should i do it right. What i am trying to achieve is to show all **advisers** from **tbl_adviser** and while also showing the class **section_id** the teacher is assigned from **tbl_section**. This is what i have come up so far.

```
 $qry_display = "SELECT a.section_id,b.*
     from tbl_section As a LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_adviser AS b ON a.section_id
                                 = b.adviser_id Where bname='$branch'";
```

My idea on $branch is that the user may only view the same data if they have the same **bname**

This is my DB structure:

tbl_section:

```
section_id
section_name
sy
adviser_id
level
bname
```

tbl_adviser:

```
adviser_id
lname_a
fname_a
address
bname
photo
cnumber
```

And this is how i suppose to show:

```
 while (@$get_display = mysql_fetch_object(@$sql_display))
            {

            ?><tbody>
            <tr>
<td  class="text"><a href="adviser_view.php?&id=
<?php echo $get_display->adviser_id ?>">
            <?php echo @$get_display->adviser_id; ?></a></td>
                <td  class="text"><?php echo @$get_display->lname_a ?></td>
                <td  class="text"><?php echo @$get_display->fname_a ?></td>
                <td  class="text"><?php echo @$get_display->section_id ?></td>


            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Edit: Error spatting out is "Column 'bname' in on clause is ambiguous".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ON` looks to me to be incorrect:

```
ON a.section_id = b.adviser_id
```

Should probably be:

```
ON a.adviser_id = b.adviser_id
```

You also need to disabmiguate the `bname` column - SQL doesn't know which table it is supposed to be coming from in the `WHERE` clause:

```
Where bname='$branch'
```

Can be:

```
Where a.bname='$branch'
```

Or:

```
Where b.bname='$branch'
```

Comment: @Tony - Answer updated. You need to say which `bname` you mean (from which table).